# Calculate the number of individual with more than i days of life with data.table in R

Tags: r, list, data.table, cumsum

Here is my simplified data.table:

| Individual | time_alive (day) |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | 1 |
| ID2 | 5 |
| ID3 | 7 |
| ID4 | 5 |

I need to calculate the number of individual alive at every day.
I achieved this by doing a loop

```
for (i in c(-1:600)) {
  y<-summarise(DT , time_alive > i )
  Alive[i+2,]<-length(y[y==TRUE])
}
```

However this is really long with a data.frame of more than 2B observations.

I wanted to try an alternative with data.table but I am stuck at only 1 day number of alive calculation:

```
DT[,.N,time_alive> i][time_alive==TRUE,2]
```

Here, i cannot be replaced by a vector but only by 1 number. I want to calculate the number of individual with more than i days of life, without doing a loop.

My result expected for the simplified data would be:

| Day | Number of individual alive |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 |

**Best solution in one line, with data.table which is much faster than looping:**

```
DT[, .(Day = seq_len(1 + max(time_alive)))][DT[,.(time_alive)], .(.N), on = .(Day <= time_alive), by = Day]
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand your question. What exactly is the variable in your column time_alive, and what output are you expecting? i. e.: What result would you want if your data would be only those 4 rows?

Comment: I edited my question so you have the results I am looking for using data.table. For the variable time_alive, for example, the individual 2 died at day 5 so he was considered alive for day 1 to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# @r2evans suggestion about making it a one-liner
# replaced res = data.table('day' = 1:max(DT$time_alive))
DT[, .(day = seq_len(1 + max(time_alive)))][
     # my original solution
     DT, .(.N) ,on = .(day <= time_alive),by = day, allow.cartesian = T]

# or 

DT[,time_alive > TARGET_NUMBER, by = individual]
```

I have two solutions based on what you have provided. One or both of them should be what you're looking for. See below for details/explanation

```
# load in data
DT = data.table('individual' = 1:4, 'time_alive' = c(1,5,7,5))
# set your target number
TARGET_NUMBER = 5

# group by individual, 
# then check if the number of days they were alive is greater than your target
# this answers "i want to calculate the number of 
# individual with more than "i" days of life

DT[,time_alive > TARGET_NUMBER, by = individual]

individual    V1
1:          1 FALSE
2:          2 FALSE
3:          3  TRUE
4:          4 FALSE

# if the result you want is that table you created. that is a little different:
# create a table with days ranging from 1 to the maximum survivor

res = data.table('day' = 1:max(DT$time_alive))

day
1:   1
2:   2
3:   3
4:   4
5:   5
6:   6
7:   7


# use joins
# join by time alive being greater than or equal to the day
# group by the specific day, and count how many observations we have
# allow.cartesian because the mapping isn't one-to-one

res[DT, .(.N) ,on = .(day <= time_alive),by = day, allow.cartesian = T]

day N
1:   1 4
2:   2 3
3:   3 3
4:   4 3
5:   5 3
6:   6 1
7:   7 1
```

Comment: I like the "join" solution, it's a data-elegant approach, +1. You can do it in one step without intermediate objects with `DT[, .(Day = seq_len(1 + max(time_alive)))][DT[,.(time_alive)], .(.N), on = .(Day <= time_alive), by = Day]`.

Comment: This answers perfectly my question, my output for the table is 50 times faster than looping. I did not think about creating a sequence, neither the "on" function. Thank you lads.

Comment: Awesome! Please accept the answer you found most useful!

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem in a different way.

If you run `data.frame(Alive = cumsum(rev(table(c(1,5,7,5)))))` (Or in your general case `data.frame(Alive = cumsum(rev(table(DT$time_alive))))`) you will have the information you need, with the only caveat that if there is any day that had no deaths, you will end up with gaps in the data.

Answer (score 0):

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT[, .(Day = seq_len(max(time_alive) + 1))
  ][, Number := rowSums(outer(Day, DT$time_alive, `<=`))]
#      Day Number
#    <int>  <num>
# 1:     1      4
# 2:     2      3
# 3:     3      3
# 4:     4      3
# 5:     5      3
# 6:     6      1
# 7:     7      1
# 8:     8      0
```

(I'm assuming that `DT` will have no more than 1 row per `Individual`.)

---

Data

```r
DT <- setDT(structure(list(Individual = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"), time_alive = c(1L, 5L, 7L, 5L)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
```